# How to fix ggplot call in rms package

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Problem**

I think I've found a bug in the `rms` package function `ggplot.Predict()` but am unable to figure out how to fix it.  When using the `ggplot.Predict()` function, the legend colors are different and the plots do not align properly; however, using the base R graphics `plot()` works just fine, so I trying to figure out what is going on with `ggplot.Predict()` function call.

My limitation in R and `ggplot` has lead me to some initial testing in the function--see What I've Tried below-- but I don't know where to proceed to fix the problem in the function call within the package.  I've filed an issue with the package maintainer and has asked me to see if I can fix it, but I have exhausted my knowledge and am reaching out for help in identifying the problem.

---

**Important to Note:**

This is the `ggplot` call from the `rms` package:

```
ggplot(zz, aes(x=.xx., y=.yhat, color=.cond)) + geom_line() + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2, 12)) + labs(x=expression(x1), y=\"y1\") + 
    theme(plot.margin = grid::unit(rep(0, 4), 'cm')) + colFun(name=expression(Set))
```

And this is the link to the function in the `rms` package:

- [ggplot.Predict - Github link](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/ggplot.Predict.s)

There is an error message relating to a deprecated parameter and is unrelated to the problem after testing.

Error:

> In addition: Warning message: `show_guide` has been deprecated. Please
>   use `show.legend` instead.

---

**Example**

I've modeled two multivariate regressions and would like to plot their fitted values with `ggplot.Predict()`. See the plots at the bottom of the question.

*Sample Data*

```
dd = data.frame(x1 = 2 + (runif(200) * 6), 
  x12 = 100 + (runif(200) * 6), 
  x13 = 1400 + (runif(200) * 600))
dd$y1 = rep(c(1.2, 1.4), each = 100) * dd$x1 + (runif(200) / 5)
```

*Model and ggplot code:*

```
library(rms)
ddist <- datadist(dd)
options("datadist" = "ddist")

g <- ols(y1 ~ x1 + x12 + x13, data = dd, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
a <- Predict(g)

h <- ols(y1 ~ I(x1^2) + I(x12^2) + I(x13^2), data = dd, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
b <- Predict(h)

p <- rbind(a,b)
ggplot(p, group = ".set.")
```

---

**What I've Tried**

It appears, after some testing, that the `colFun()` is causing some of the problems (See lines 376 and 474).  On line 376, if `aestype[1]` is changed to `aestype[2]` then the palette change to the same throughout the plot, but the legend colors are different.  On line 474, it appears to check for the number of plots and assign the palette, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
  376:   colFun <- if(aestype[1] == 'color') colorscale else
  474:   colFun <- if(aestype[j] == 'color') colorscale else
```

---

**Plots**

- `ggplot` showing the problem

[image]

- R Base `plot`
  [image]
- `ggplot` after changing `aestype[1]` to `aestype[2]`

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you get anything out of that ggplot statement. I thought you always needed an aes() :P

Comment: @Richo64 It's because the `rms` package has a special function `ggplot.predict` or just `ggplot` in the package that takes care of the call, but I can't figure out why it's doing this with groups.

Comment: Is the question why the two lines in `ggplot` are a different color than the two lines made with `plot`?

Comment: @kristang No. The question is why are the colors different in the legend and lines for the ggplot code. I'd like the ggplot code to work like the plot code.

Comment: When I run your code I get a warning from `ggplot2` stating that "`show_guide` has been deprecated. Please use `show.legend` instead."
If I had to guess`rms` based their internal function for plotting with `ggplot2` on an earlier version?

Comment: @kristang I tried downgrading ggplot to the previous version but with no luck. A dependency for rms is hmisc which requires ggplot 2.0

Comment: Then I think your best bet is manually plotting the whole thing by hand - i.e. plotting the lines then taking the SE and adding them as the shaded areas. 
Alternatively, find the issue (if this is indeed and issue and not intended behavior) in the code and report it to the `rms` developers?

Comment: @kristang Thanks. I've considered reporting it but wanted to see if it is really an error and if anyone else has run in to this. Plotting it by hand is my next plan of attack if it is a bug

Comment: If you find a solution consider adding it to the original post, or adding it as an answer so others can benefit from it if they find themselves in the same position.

Comment: The issue seems to be in the custom function `ggplot.Predict`, it defines a manual colorscale with a colorblind-friendly palette. (See the package info at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf, page 56/57 or `?ggplot.Predict`.

Comment: Addition: I tried to fiddle around with color-palettes, but couldn't get it to function properly as it appears that the first panel uses a different palette than the second panel.

Comment: @Heroka Thanks for messing around with it.  I think I'll post this as an issue on the packages github and update the question with what I find out.

Comment: @Heroka I've added the full ggplot call from the package.  Any idea where the problem is occuring?

Comment: @Amstell probably the `colFun(name=expression(Set))` line? [Looking at the github version](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/a176ffdb14aa87d3ca0137a9a1da6a5105efa48b/R/ggplot.Predict.s) looks like `colFun` is defined internally to `ggplot.Predict.s` on lines 376 or 474, depending on the `j` value (whatever that is). It appears to be pasting together a standard ggplot scale as a string and then accessing it via `get`.

Comment: You can also see where `show_guide` is being used (line 281), but that is *just a warning*, not an error like your question currently states, and I think it's probably not related (also as your question currently states).

Comment: @Gregor Thanks.  yes the show_guide is not the problem but in the ggplot call.  Any idea how to remedy that?

Comment: It's a 540 line function with, at a glance, about 30 lines of comments. It would probably take me several hours to figure out what it's doing. You could fork the repo and step through it line by line and try to work out what's what, but that's far beyond my motivation.

Comment: @Gregor  No problem.  I appreciate you pointing out the appropriate lines.  I'm working through it now.

Comment: maybe worth filing a github issue about this?

Comment: @BenBolker I've already filed an issue about this and am trying to fix it, but am now stuck and reaching out for help.